# Updating Multiple Tables with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Controller for editing.

```
    // POST: Clients/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Guid id, [Bind("ClientID,DOB,Name,NameID,Address,AddressID,ContactDetails,GPDoctors")] Clients clients)
    {
        if (id != clients.ClientID)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(clients);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ClientsExists(clients.ClientID))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(clients);
    }
```

When editing data in the Create form, instead of the original data in the foreign table being edited and saved, the data is saved in a new row. The Guid ID foreign key that is present in both tables is replaced with the Guid of the new row from the foreign table. The data in the primary table is saved correctly however.

I'm very new to Asp.net core and ef core so any help and guidance would be greatly appretiated.

EDIT 1
Client Model

```
using IWCaseManagerWebApp.Models;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace IWCaseManager.Models
{
public class Clients
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ClientID { get; set; }

    public virtual Names Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Addresses Address { get; set; }
}
}
```

Addresses Model Child

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace IWCaseManagerWebApp.Models
{
public class Addresses
{
    [Key]
    public Guid AddressID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(64)]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(32)]
    public string Town { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(32)]
    public string County { get; set; }

    [StringLength(8, MinimumLength = 4)]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Validated { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please show what Update method is doing?  Most probably, everything is going with EntityState.Added; I don't see code where you attach the entities to context or manually setting the entity state to modified.

Comment: Could you post your db model(Clients and child entities)? And what is the model data you received in edit method?

Comment: @ademcaglin Clients and child models have been added. Due to my lack of experience and understanding of asp.net could you reword your questions in order that i can understand. Thanks

Comment: As pointed by @Developer, you probably missed to attach address entity. Try : `context.Entry(clients.Address).State = clients.Address.AddressID == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: @ademcaglin When making an update, the Controller will load the data that is in the Clients and Address tables, apart from the AddressID GUID which returns as an empty GUID. Which is why when saving the updated data it returns as a new row as it is creating a new GUID ID, instead of saving the updated data under the original AddressID GUID